# CMAKE options to -DXXX compiler arguments

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

I have a C/C++ project compiled with `gcc` and using `cmake 2.8+`. I know `cmake` supports some `OPTION(XXX "Description..." ON/OFF)` tag. I would like that these build options result somehow in `-DXXX` compile time arguments passed to `gcc`. How to do that most elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only care about adding -D compiler flags then the command you want is

[add_definitions()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_definitions)

You could wrap that in a if() block to be turned on with the related option():

```
option(MY_FUNCTIONALITY "Cool functionality" ON)

if(MY_FUNCTIONALITY)
  add_definitions(-DENABLE_MY_FUNCTIONALITY)
endif()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `endif(MY_FUNCTIONALITY)`?

Comment: That used to be the required syntax, however its now an optional thing.  Stylistically I'm not sure what is preferred.

Comment: Leaving the closing commands empty (like the answer does) is certainly preferred style in modern CMake. DRY and all that.